# Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):

Tags: exception, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using glassfish 4 to deploy my app, but I encounter the following error:

```
can not Deploy myapplication
deploy is failing = Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [MyApplication]: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions:
-------------------------------------------------- -------

Runtime Exceptions:
-------------------------------------------------- -------

java.lang.NullPointerException
. Please see server.log for more details.
```

and could not yet understand the cause or the solution of this problem.
the detail is that I am using the following dependence JPA implementation:

dependency
groupId> org.eclipse.persistence groupId
artifactId eclipselink artifactId
version> 2.4.0 version
 dependency

and javax.persistence-2.0.4.v201112161009.jar

Comment: Did you check the server logs? There should be an exception with (hopefully) more information as to what caused the failure.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario I have encountered this error is when there is an abstract JPA Entity with no concrete class below it. Make sure all your abstract JPA entities are extended to create concrete JPA entities.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when upgrading eclipselink from 2.6.5 to 2.7.

Because, my POM.xml had line below, I had to delete it, and just put new version to 2.7.4
for the **artifactId eclipselink** to latest version and problem was fixed.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```